# Python3: correct usage of __init__ in metaclass

Tags: python

`MyMeta.__init__` is implemented as following. Should this function return anything? It's return an instance now, does this has any impact?  What are the usage examples for writing a custom `__init__` function inside a metaclass?

```
class MyMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        print("***MyMeta.__new__ called")
        instance = super(MyMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)
        instance.v_new = "v_new"
        return instance

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        print("***MyMeta.__init__ called")
        instance = super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        return instance 


class AClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        print("@@@AClass.__init__ called")


print("---> ")
a = AClass()
print(a.v_new)
```

Comment: The instances of metaclasses are classes. So the `__init__()` method is called when you define a new class that uses this as its metaclass. It's called just like any other `__init__()` method. The instance has already been created -- it's in the `cls` parameter -- and the return value isn't used.

Comment: There's an example of using `__init__()` in the metaclass at https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/. It sets a class attribute in each class that's defined using the metaclass.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MetaClass(type):
    """
    Class is object. By default, "type" created the in memory class object.
    Instance is object. Class created the in memory instance object.
    """
    meta_counter = 0

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        print("***MyMeta.__new__(): control class object creation")
        cls_object = super(MetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)
        return cls_object

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        print("***MyMeta.__init__() class-wide initializer")
        cls.cls_order = MetaClass.meta_counter
        MetaClass.meta_counter += 1


class AClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        print("AClass.__init__()")


class BClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass


class XClass:
    def __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):
        print("ZClass.__new__(): constructor")
        instance = super(XClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("ZClass.__init__(): instance-wide initializer")
        self.id = 1


print("\n\n---> ")
a = AClass()
print(a.cls_order)
b = BClass()
print(b.cls_order)

print(MetaClass.meta_counter)

print("\n\n***> ")
XClass('my-name')
```